# "Error 2147217904 No value given for one or more required parameters" When trying to fetch data using "WHERE" where clause in Excel

Tags: database, vbscript, macros, xlsx, adodb

I am trying to fetch data from Excel (as Database) when I put simple select query "select * from [Sheet1$]" its working fine and retrieve the data from sheet1. but when I put the conditional statement (where or Like) its throws the error "Error 2147217904 No value given for one or more required parameters".

Query Which is throw error ---

"select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE [Sheet1$].[ColName]= User"
OR

"select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE [ColName] = " & ColName_RunTime
OR
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:E2] WHERE ColName =Yes"

Thanks in advance for help or solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is 0x80040E10L DB_E_PARAMNOTOPTIONAL No value given for one or more required parameters. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171852(v=sql.110).aspx

Effectively, as you point out, there's something wrong with how you are supplying the values for your WHERE clause. It appears that you want to supply a string, so, they must be enclosed in single quotes.

```
"select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE [Sheet1$].[ColName]= 'User' "
```